# Azure WebJob won't run in VS 2015?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm new to Azure WebJobs development and I am trying to test out my WebJob in Visual Studio. My job runs continuosly, but does not execute the runWebJob() method? that I have specified in the host.CallAsync line. Here's my code:

```
public class Program {
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }
        var host = new JobHost(config);

        host.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod("runWebJob"));
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();

    }

    [NoAutomaticTrigger]
    public static async Task runWebJob()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("RUNNING METHOD"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the console output when you try to run this application?

Comment: No output at all. It reaches host.CallAsync with no problem but does nothing...

Comment: I see this in my locals when it runs Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync  Id = 8, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"

Comment: Try adding .Wait() to the end of the CallAsync() method.  It should run anyway but it is an async call and you'll want to be explicit about when you are expecting it to complete.

Comment: @MCooper your function is not asynchronous, it will run synchronously because it lacks the await keyword in it.

Comment: I think I declared it as an asynchronous function correctly. [Asynchronous Functions in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh191443(vs.110).aspx) @Thomas

Comment: @MichaelWeinand I did this but it still does not run the function when I start the application.

Answer (score 2):

I test with you mentioned code. We need to set  *class Program* **public**. Then it should work.

As your async function no await, I add await for test.

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }
        var host = new JobHost();

        host.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod("runWebJob"));
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();

    }
    [NoAutomaticTriggerAttribute]
    public static async Task runWebJob()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); //just for test
        Console.WriteLine("RUNNING METHOD");
    }
```

I test it on my side.

[image]

**Note:** If you change `host.CallAsync(typeof(Program).GetMethod("runWebJob"))` to `host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("runWebJob"))` and change the function to synchronously function then you could see the detail error.

[image]

**Update:**

By default, the WebJobs SDK looks for connection strings named AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard

If you haven't added the following connection string in the app.config file, please have a try to add it. More details please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/websites-dotnet-webjobs-sdk-get-started).

```
 <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[accountname];AccountKey=[accesskey]"/>
        <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=[accountname];AccountKey=[accesskey]"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me...My code still won't run? Could this be because of an issue with my App.config file? All I want to do is run this to see if it works in VS Studio.

Comment: I have updated answer. If you haven't added the AzureWebJobsStorage connection string  please add it in the app.config file. If it doesn't work,could you supply more info about it.

Comment: Sun MSFT I have the following in my App.config file :                              `<add name="AzureWebJobsDashboard" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"/>
    <add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;"/>`

Comment: If you don't start Storage Emulator,please have a try to start it. Or could you please have a try to use Azure storage account connection string?

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: I tried adding config to `var host = JobHost(config)` and added a connection string for an Azure Storage Account for both AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsDashboard. I still can't get it to run in the debbuger?

Comment: Please have a try to use  host.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod("runWebJob")) and change the function to synchronously function then you could see the detail error.  If it is possible, please add the screenshot for the detail error.

Comment: Do you use the proxy in your computer? It seems that you can't connect to storage.